# GPU not listed when "activate tensorflow"

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am new to using Tensorflow with Anaconda. Noticed something weird. With tensorflow 1.1.0 (not activated), it found the GPU. With tensorflow 1.8.0 (when activated), it didn't, only CPU. Also the Python version are different.

First case, simply opened up a terminal and ran python.

```
D:\>python

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(tf.__version__)
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

Result:

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

1.1.0

[name: "/cpu:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 13639212131358291434
, name: "/gpu:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 6740156088
locality {
bus_id: 1
}
incarnation: 5753593935959021307
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0"
]
```

Second case: "activate tensorflow"

```
D:\>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) D:\> python
```

Run same commands. And the result:

```
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr  7 2018, 04:52:34) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

1.8.0

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 2929636256184659033
]
```

Comment: [Did you](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#installing_with_anaconda) run "pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu "

Comment: Yes I did. That's how I got Tensorflow 1.8. Then I noticed the differences.